# eMMC device ( connected to mmctosd adapter ) detected as sdb not as mmcblk0 in ubuntu

Tags: drivers, hard-drive, sd-card, emmc, mmc

I have connected emmc device to linux pc with mmctosd adapter and it is getting detected as sdb device. But now I want to use mmc-utils package ( mmc commands ). I think this cannot be used on sdb devices. so help me if anyone finds solution on using mmc-utils package on sd devices